# Unfortunately, Package installer has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm building an app with Eclipse (to Android). If I try to start my application from Eclipse and I have connect to my pc my smartphone, I can use my application.
Now I want to build an .APK file from Eclipse. Then I have copy apk file into my device, so I use MyFiles app, search the apk, clik on it to install the application but I have this stange error:

> Unfortunately, Package installer has stopped.

Now I don't know how can I fixed it.
This is my mainfest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mcSolution"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mcSolution.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.main.nuovoOrdine"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.ordine.creaOrdine"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.ordine.mainOrdine"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.ordine.viewOrdine"></activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.mcSolution.setting.setting"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.articoli.viewArticoli"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.clienti.mainClienti"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.clienti.viewClienti"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.clienti.infoCliente"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.clienti.operazioniCliente"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mcSolution.clienti.operazioniClienteDettaglio"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be anything, including broken APK ... You should use adb to see the error details.

```
adb logcat
```

Comment: I have see that, If I try to install the apk in my tablet with Android 4.0.3 I don't have the problem. The error that I have is on my smartphone with Android 5.0.1.
For case it is this the problem?

Comment: Thats why u have to look into logs. Just run the log monitor and try the installation again. Once it failed u should see the exception. At least provide it here if it is unclear for u, otherwise it could be million and one reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your permission section is ok. Normally this type of problem happened for the following reasons:

- Less Memory in your device
- missing any permission

Comment: I have see that, If I try to install the apk in my tablet with Android 4.0.3 I don't have the problem. The error that I have is on my smartphone with Android 5.0.1. For case it is this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your app assets and app icon should not be too much big images and resources.